# Insert rows to excel spreadsheet using LabVIEW

Tags: excel, labview

I have a excel spreadsheet which just contains data in the rng A1:A24.

aaa

aaa

aaa

aaa

aaa

..

..

..

I want to add one col of data before this col. So it will have 2 col:

bbb aaa

bbb aaa

bbb aaa

... ...

... ...

... ...

... ...

How to do it in LabView?

Answer (score 2):

Read/Write spreadsheet file VIs don't read .xls files.  This will work fine for .csv, though.  [This thread](http://forums.ni.com/t5/BreakPoint/Excel-Board/m-p/379682) on the NI forum that contains a ton of stuff related to manipulating Excel files in LabVIEW.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps from NI: [Reading Microsoft Excel Numeric Data Into LabVIEW](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/99F61B6AB9CD6AFA8625734600814D6B). 
Quoting the link:

> **Use the Read From Measurement File
>   Express VI:**
>
> You may read numeric data
>   in an Excel spreadsheet into LabVIEW
>   using the Read From Measurement File
>   Express VI through a two step process.
>   First, save your Excel spreadsheet as
>   a tab delimited text file.  Then,
>   rename the *.txt file as a *.lvm file.
>   The Read From Measurement File Express
>   VI can now read the numeric data into
>   LabVIEW.  The following steps will
>   walk you through the procedure.
>
> 1. Open your Excel spreadsheet containing simple numeric information.
> 2. Save your Excel spreadsheet as a tab delimited text file.
> 3. Click OK.  Note that you are only saving numeric data from the
>      active worksheet.
> 4. Click Yes.
> 5. Close your Microsoft Excel document.
> 6. Navigate to the location where you saved your Excel document as a tab
>      delimited text file, right-click on
>      your filename.txt document, select
>      Rename, and rename you file with a
>      .lvm extension so that your file now
>      appears as filename.lvm.
> 7. Read your numeric spreadsheet data into LabVIEW by specifying
>      filename.lvm as the File Name in the
>      Read From Measurement File Express VI
>      configuration window.
>
> Navigate to the location where you
>   saved your Excel document as a tab
>   delimited text file, right-click on
>   your filename.txt document, select
>   Rename, and rename you file with a
>   .lvm extension so that your file now
>   appears as filename.lvm.
>
> **Use the Read From Spreadsheet File VI:**
>
> The LabVIEW VI 'Read From Spreadsheet
>   File.VI' does not directly read .xls
>   files, but rather delimited text
>   files.
>
> If you created your Excel spreadsheet
>   by manually entering the data in (not
>   using LabVIEW and the Write to
>   Spreadsheet File VI) the Read From
>   Spreadsheet File VI will not properly
>   interpret your .xls file and will
>   return zeros into your array.  In
>   order to get this data into an array
>   in LabVIEW you will have to save the
>   Excel file as a tab delimited text
>   file. The procedure for this can be
>   seen in the example above.  Now
>   inputting this new .txt file into the
>   file path node of the Read From
>   Spreadsheet File VI will populate your
>   array with the proper data. If you
>   just need the first column of data,
>   you can wire a True constant to the
>   Transpose? node, and the First Row
>   output will give you an array with the
>   values of your first column of data.